# Showing characters in extended ASCII code (Ubuntu)

Tags: c, ubuntu, ascii

I need to print characters part of ASCII extended, namely something like:

```
char p = 219; // a rectangle   
printf("%c\n", p);
```

However, in the shell it does not show the proper character .. what can i do to see the rectangle?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use a virtual terminal that supports extended ASCII. The default terminal in Ubuntu is gnome-terminal. You will have to [change the character encoding](http://library.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/stable/gnome-terminal-usage.html.en#gnome-terminal-encoding) in gnome-terminal from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-2 or use another terminal. [Konsole](http://konsole.kde.org/) for instance.

Comment: Konsole works the same! it does not print the right ascii character

Comment: Either way, modern Linux terminals will be UTF-8. You want some other character set.

Comment: That's correct. But it's easy to configure Konsole into into using ISO-8859-2.

Answer (score 2):

Use libiconv to convert the CP-1252 or ISO-8859-1 or whatever 8-bit character set you are converting from to UTF-8; something like this:

```
#include <iconv.h>
iconv_t cd = iconv_open("utf-8", "cp-1252");
iconv(cd, &inbuf, sizeof(inbuf), &outbuf, sizeof(outbuf)); // <- psuedocode, change to meet your needs
```

Comment: that would be cp437, cp850 or another one of the myriad DOS codepages. There is no rectangle on ISO-8859-1.

Comment: If it's a fixed character, there is no sense in using `iconv`. Simply lookup the unicode codepoint number or the UTF-8 for it and hard-code.

Comment: @ninjalj: Sure, whatever. That's the asker's responsibility.

@R: Sure. But the asker says "I need to print characters". Maybe they have more characters than just (char)219.

Comment: yes.. in fact i want to print that character a number of times!

Comment: You can convert the character once and then re-use the UTF-8 buffer, of course.

Answer (score 0):

For me, a working codepage is **IBM850**.
Using **konsole**, in profile configuration, advanced tab, you can choose the codepage.
I am able to display extended ascii this way (usefull for IPMI bios access).