# How do I print the infinity symbol in C using printf

Tags: c, ascii, printf

I tried the following

```
printf ("%c", 236);   //236 is the ASCII value for infinity
```

But I am just getting garbage output on the screen.

printf was working correctly for ASCII values less than 128. So I tried the following

```
printf ("%c", 236u);  //unsigned int 236
```

Still I am just getting garbage only. So, what should I do to make printf display ASCII values from 128 to 255.

Comment: 236 is most certainly not the "ASCII value for infinity". ASCII is only defined up to 127. The rest are "code pages".

Comment: Oh. I was referring this link http://www.cdrummond.qc.ca/cegep/informat/Professeurs/Alain/files/ascii.htm. In that case how do I print the infinity symbol?

Comment: printf("\xe2\x88\x9e\n");

Comment: on `MinGW`, I was able to get infinity symbol with `printf("Infinity is %c\n", 236);`

Comment: I think you are going to need to work out what code page you are using. It's no use if you are using ASCII since that doesn't contain infinity.

Comment: @Ganesh : That means that the symbol ∞ is actually `236` in the code page that your OS currently uses.

Comment: @Karthik It is possible that your console can't display that character. Check the  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781447/showing-characters-in-extended-ascii-code-ubuntu)k by DhruvPathak

Comment: The output you see depends on the locale configured in your terminal. Still, ASCII is only defined upto 127. You might probably look into `UTF-8` and use `wprintf` to print instead, after setting the correct locale in your program using `setlocale`.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar .. Yes, I ran this on `Windows 7` machine with `MinGW` support. I feel that link in DhruvPathak's comment is very apt as the display of special characters is dependent on the terminal.

Comment: Karthik, the link you gave is outdated. The codepage shown is OEM 437 or better known as IBM-PC character set. You would need to use MS-DOS or the command line under Windows to display your character. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like everyone else in the comments already mentioned, you would not be able to reliably print characters after 127 (and assuming it as ASCII)  since ASCII is only defined upto 127. Also the output you see very much depends on the terminal settings (i.e. which locale it is configured to).

If you're fine using UTF-8 to print, you could give `wprintf` a try as shown below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{
    setlocale( LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8" );
    wprintf (L"%lc\n", 8734);
    return 0;
}
```

It would produce the following output:

```
∞
```

[`8734`](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8576) (or `0x221E`) is the equivalent of the UTF-8 UNICODE character for the symbol `∞`.

Comment: note that this will not work with MSVC since it does not support [`setlocale`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x99tb11d(v=vs.110).aspx) with UTF8

Comment: @msam - I hardly use Windows environment for compiling and do not have one handy right now. Do you know the equivalent English US UTF-8 locale which needs to be set for MSVC ? I can update the answer with that info. :)

Comment: On windows `setlocale( LC_ALL, "C" ); wprintf (L"%lc\n", 236);` (or just `printf ("%c", 236);` since the C locale is set anyway on program startup) does it for the infinity (∞) symbol - but this is , of course, specific to this case.

Answer (score 0):

Standard C does not have a symbol for infinite. That's for your implementation (eg. your compiler, your operating system, your terminal and your hardware) to define. Consider that C was designed with portability for systems that use non-ASCII character sets in mind (eg. EBCDIC).