# How to print root symbol with c in a file

Tags: c, file-io, ascii

I have a file named **output.txt** and i want to print in a root **(√)** symbol in it. 
Here is my program

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main(void)
{
    FILE *fptr;     
    fptr = fopen("output.txt","w+"); //open the file to write 
    fprintf(fptr,"\xfb");            // \xfb is the hexadecimal code for root symbol
    fclose(fptr);
}
```

but when i run the program **(û)** is printed in it

Comment: `û` is the unicode character for codepoint `\xfb`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you are encountering is because you are attempting to use part of the extended ASCII set (ie: characters above 127 in value). The *code page* is something you set so that if the MSB of an 8-bit ASCII symbol is set, it can map to one of many different code pages depending on region/locale, OS, etc (ie: Greek, Latin, etc). In most cases, ASCII characters are generally considered to be 7-bit, ignoring the code page enable bit.

Attempting to use extended ASCII is not a portable approach, so your best alternative is to:

1. Make use of unicode
2. Make sure your C compiler is C99 compliant.

The following example resolves the original problem.

**Source Code**

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(void) {
    FILE *fptr;     
    fptr = fopen("output.txt","w+"); //open the file to write 
    fprintf(fptr, "\u221A\n");
    fclose(fptr);
}
```

**Output from Sample Run**

---

```
√
```

**References**

---

1. *How to print Extended ASCII characters 127 to 160 in through a C program?*, Accessed 2014-04-16, [`<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16359225/how-to-print-extended-ascii-characters-127-to-160-in-through-a-c-program>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16359225/how-to-print-extended-ascii-characters-127-to-160-in-through-a-c-program)
2. *Unicode Character 'SQUARE ROOT' (U+221A)*, Accessed 2014-04-16, [`<http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/221a/index.htm>`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/221a/index.htm)

Comment: Just to add to this a bit... 0xfb is the square root sign in code page 437 (old DOS/Windows). More modern versions of Windows do not seem to include the square root sign in the typical code pages 1250 or 1252, and it is also not present in any of the ISO-8859 character sets, it seems. So, unless you can ensure a terminal environment that is set for code page 437, the Unicode `\u221a` in a properly configured Unicode-capable terminal is the way to go.

Comment: @twalberg how can i ensure a terminal enviroment is set to code page 437

Comment: You'll need to make sure you have 1) fonts that support CP437, 2) a CP437 based locale installed, 3) a terminal emulator that will support CP437, and possibly some other things, then make sure they're all configured correctly... You'd have less work just going the Unicode route, I think, at least on modern systems, because CP437 is widely considered obsolete/deprecated/dead.