# Print extended ASCII char in C, Linux

Tags: c, linux, codepages

Im trying to print all extended ASCII chars. I have found a code on forum:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {
    wchar_t c;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "C");

    for (c = 128; c < 256; c++) {
        wprintf(L"char nr %d: %lc\n", c, c);
    }
    printf("\n%s\n", setlocale(0, NULL));

    std::cin.get();
    std::cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

This code is working in windows in VS 2017.
[image]

In the screenshot, you can see the result of this code in windows and Linux. I know that problem is with coding, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Consider the settings of gnome-terminal?

Comment: What is the value of $LANG environment variable in linux?

Comment: This program is in C++, not C. The code is ok, the problem is with your terminal/program that is used to display (it does not support extended ascii when using wide characters). Windows uses encoding that does support extended ascii with `wprintf`.

Comment: LANG = pl_PL.UTF-8, terminal character encoding is UNICODE-utf8.

Comment: @KamilCuk How can I fix it?

Comment: No need for `wprintf` here. OP only uses narrow chars.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use symbols of extended ASCII table in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17362509/608639), [How to print Extended ASCII characters 127 to 160 in through a C program?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16359225/608639), etc.

Comment: @jww I saw this page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, all is fine. ASCII characters are limited below 128. What come above depends on the actual character set.

In Linux, you are displaying a subset of the ISO-8859-1 (aka Latin1) character set, while on Windows you are displaying the Windows code page 850. As you declare a UTF8 charset on Linux, you should only display error characters, but your terminal seems to interpret some bytes as latin1.

If you want to display all Latin1 characters, just change the `LANG` environment variable:

```
export LANG=pl_PL.ISO-8859-1
```

Or as you language seems to be Polish, ISO-8859-2 is probably more appropriate:

```
export LANG=pl_PL.ISO-8859-2
```

Comment: @magnus250: Run `sudo localedef -f ISO-8859-2 pl_PL pl_PL.ISO-8859-2` to define the Polish ISO-8859-2 locale, then retry. It will work.  Everyone except Microsoft has basically moved to UTF-8 locales, and that's why that ISO-8859-2 variant is not installed in your Linux machine by default, and you need to install it yourself to replicate Windows behaviour.

Comment: @NominalAnimal I do this. When I put locale in console i get LANG=pl_PL.ISO-8859-2, but this code still not working :(.

Comment: okay, I do all your tips. I use printf("%d - \%c\n, i,i) to print all extended ascii and it works. Thanks you :)